# How to create 'backgroundColor' gradient in Angular Chart.js

Tags: angular, charts

I am trying to implement the `chart.js` in Angular using `ng2-chart`. I need `backgroundColor` as a gradient in line chart.

Is there any way to get chart in a gradient.

```
public lineChartColors: Color[] = [
    {
     borderColor: '#813d7e',
     backgroundColor: 'rgba(129, 61, 126, 0.25)',
     borderWidth: 2,
     pointBackgroundColor:'#fff',

    },
  ];
```

You can visit for live code on [Stackbiltz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-line-template)

Comment: Please check this link https://codepen.io/plavookac/pen/RKjNEV

Comment: I have already worked on it, but I need this in Angular. Visit the code here https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-line-template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control canvas by `ViewChild`

```
@ViewChild('myCanvas') canvas: ElementRef;

<canvas #myCanvas  baseChart ...
```

and set your color like that

```
 const gradient = this.canvas.nativeElement.getContext('2d').createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 600);
      gradient.addColorStop(0, 'red');
      gradient.addColorStop(1, 'green');
      this.lineChartColors = [
          {
              backgroundColor: gradient
          }
 ];
```

Please examine https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-line-template-rqccsu

Answer (score 0):

Please Check Below link it solves your problem
[create the line chart with gradient colors and animation.](https://blog.vanila.io/chart-js-tutorial-how-to-make-gradient-line-chart-af145e5c92f9)